# appending a div at the end of a dynamically created row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have rows that are dynamically created and I want to append a div at the end of each row. I tried different ways to get this to happen. one time I ended up appending the div to each row but the previous rows got additional divs every time a row was added. I want only one row to have 1 cancel div at all time. (this will be like a cancel button so the user can delete the row).

in this code i am trying to go through each row with the class of row and check to see if the row has a child with a class of "cancel" and if there is none append the div cancel. It works the first time but not the other times.

```
$('.row').each(function(){
 if($(".row").children(".cancel").length == 0){
    $("<div class = 'cancel'>test</div>").appendTo('.row')
}   
})
```

I tried to add the div "cancel" in the else statement when I append the rows like this

```
 if($(".table").html().length <= 0)
 {
    $('.table').append($("<table>").append(tableheader).append(tr));

}else{
    if($(".table").html().length > 0){
        $("table").append(tr).append("<div class = 'cancel'>test</div>")

    }

}
```

but it didn't show up at all

I know I could probably add another td to the var tr to make a new column with the div, but I'm wondering why my efforts to doing it the above way was a unsuccessful. It should work. excuse my ignorance .

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/bDPM6/) for illustration. maybe there is something wrong with the code somewhere else.

I have another problem in the code that I think that you could help me out with. Its with the total amount in the total column. the format is coming out as 7.5 instead of 7.50, normal dollar pricing figures. and when im on grilled chicken cutlet and choose qnty = 3 the total is 38.849999999999994 i thought toFixed(2) and parseFloat would fix that but they didn't work. obviously I would like 38.85.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you are accessing the table rows while appending the div.

```
$('.row').each(function(){
    if($(".row").children(".cancel").length == 0){
        $("<div class = 'cancel'>test</div>").appendTo('.row')
    }   
});
```

The above script always searches for the class `.row` while appending the div. So if you have a div appended to any one of the `.row` class, if condition fails.

Solution:

To fix the problem, use `$(this)` to access the each row in the loop.

```
$('.row').each(function(){
    if($(this).children(".cancel").length == 0){
        $("<div class = 'cancel'>test</div>").appendTo($(this))
    }   
});
```

Also to fix your second issue of price, change

```
$(".total",$row).html(parseFloat(qnty * price));
```

to

```
$(".total",$row).html(parseFloat(qnty * price).toFixed(2));
```

Check the updated [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDPM6/3).

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. so I have to put in this to select the row that I was using the .each method for to check each row. if i just use $('.row') it doesn't necessarily mean that it is getting the $('row')  i first started checking with the .each(). I wish I could use $('.row') but I got to start getting used to using $(this) in other similar cases.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.row').each(function(idx, val){
    if($(val).children(".cancel").length == 0){
        $("<div class = 'cancel'>test</div>").appendTo(val);
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me a way to solve this problem. so just to clarify val is representing the element row and you are using it in the conditional statement to refer to the original selected row that is being using the .each(). I had $(".row") instead of val in the conditional statement and that was incorrect because $('.row')  was not referring to the $('.row').each. Is that a corect assumptions. If so I guess the $('.row') in the conditional statements that i had for my solution was referring to nothing because nothing was happening?

Comment: yup, actually $('.row').each is selecting all the elements which are having .row class, and in the function, you can access the actual object through parameters, which is val in this case.

Comment: and in your solution, your condition if($(".row").children(".cancel").length == 0){ is nullifying the append.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do this
      a)console.log($('.row').length)// to see the length
2. $("test").appendTo('.row') //this.code should "**$("test").appendTo($(this))** "

   I think what i say above may helpful; try your self